# AIRFLOW - programmatically List, trigger and stop the DAGS using API

Tags: python, airflow-scheduler, airflow

I want to create python program which can List All active (ON/OFF) DAGS currently on UI.
Also want to trigger any DAG out of the list or Stop the DAG in between via python

Is there any Python API to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

In `Airflow>=2.0` you can do that with the Rest API.

You will need to use several endpoints for that ([List DAGs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/get_dags), [Trigger a new DAG run](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/get_dags), [Update a DAG](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/patch_dag))

In `Airflow<2.0` you can do some of that using the [experimental API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/rest-api-ref.html).

Comment: Can you tell me the url as well to use for get request for list DAGS

Comment: @user14808811 It's listed in the documentation I shared. In the upper right corner you have `GET /dags` click on it and you will see the URL.

Comment: is this for airflow >= 2.0 ? also URL link is "https://airflow.apache.org/api/v1/dags" however I expose to localhost:8080 , I use airflow 1.10.10 so http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dags is not working

Comment: can you help me with trigger and stop/pause the DAGS for airflow 1.10.10

Comment: It's listed in the link I provided. `GET /api/experimental/dags/<DAG_ID>/paused/<string:paused>`
  Please read the docs I shared.

Comment: Is there any API for airflow 1.10.10 to stop/kill the tasks within DAG or entire DAG ? I am looking for option to kill the DAG. I know PAUSE/UNPAUSE but it allows the running DAG/task to finish